# C# Rest Service that Utilizes google maps api key works locally but not on server

Tags: c#, rest, google-maps

So I have to develop a rest web service in C# that uses google maps to do some geo-coding. My IService.cs essentially has one method:

findNearest(string address, string addresses);

Which is implemented in the Service1.cs. I have a google maps key which is coded in the service implementation in Service1.cs.

When I test my service locally, it works fine.

However, when I deploy it into my schools server, I get a {Request Error}, {The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.}

I have no idea what is going on. I had to download a lot of dependencies in visual studio to get the code to run. What am I missing? How do I fix this. Do I have to edit some visual studio generated file to get my project to run on the server or is it a problem with the google maps key and how I am invoking the api.

I have no idea were to begin in tackling this. It must be something with permissions either in my schools server or with the google maps api and how im invoking it with my current key. The contents of the method are below.

```
GMapProviders.GoogleMap.ApiKey = @"MYKEY";
GMaps.Instance.Mode = AccessMode.ServerAndCache;
double distance;
GeoCoderStatusCode statusCode;
var dest = GoogleMapProvider.Instance.GetPoint(destAddress, out statusCode);
var appLoc = GoogleMapProvider.Instance.GetPoint(addresses[0], out 
    statusCode);
var route = GoogleMapProvider.Instance.GetRoute((PointLatLng)dest, 
    (PointLatLng)appLoc, false, false, 14);
distance = route.Distance;
for (int i = 1; i < applicants.Length; i++){
//Internal Logic and series of Google Maps API calls like above
}

return nearest;
```

Comment: There is insufficient detail here. I'd look for differences in C# version. Please use more whitespace in you question to make this more readable and use {} to format error messages.

Comment: Noted. I tried to clean it up. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with your API key restriction, have you applied any restrictions in your API key?